# How to check generic method parameter to avoid ClassCastException?

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

Java uses type erasure wherever applicable, but, of course, when invoking methods the parameter types must match.

**How to avoid a `ClassCastException` when I cannot ensure the type at compile time?** Example:

```
class KeyedHashSet<K,E> // implements Set<E>
{ final Map<K,E> map = new HashMap<>();
  final Function<E,K> keyExtractor; // extracts intrusive key from value

  public KeyedHashSet(Function<E,K> keyExtractor)
  { this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor; }

  public boolean contains(Object o)
  { if (o != null)
      try
      { @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // <- BAD
        K key = keyExtractor.apply((E)o);
        E elem = map.get(key);
        return elem != null && elem.equals(o);
      } catch (ClassCastException ex) // <- EVIL!!!
      {}
    return false;
  }
  // more methods
}
```

The method `Set.contains` takes an arbitrary object as parameter. But I cannot extract the key required for my hash lookup from *an arbitrary* object. This only works for objects of type E.

In fact I am not interested in the key when the object is not of type E because in this case I am sure that the collection does not contain the object.

But the above work around with catching the `ClassCastException` has several drawbacks:

- First of all, one should not throw an exception when this is a normal program path.
- Secondly, I might catch a `ClassCastException` thrown from deep inside the `keyExtractor` implementation, which is *not intended*.

**Is it possible to check the type of `o` against the parameter of `keyExtractor` *before* the call to `.apply`** and without unreasonable runtime overhead?

---

Note: I know that the above design requires E to have an immutable key. But this is no big deal and happens quite often.

Comment: Pass the class of the value as argument to the constructor of the KeyedHashSet, and use it to check if the object is an instance of that class: `public KeyedHashSet(Function<E,K> keyExtractor, Class<E> clazz)`. Or just accept the drawback. If the extractor has a bug, too bad for the caller: he introduced a bug, and it's his problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that I can avoid type erasure by this hack. But this would require any user of this class to provide the type explicitly. The idea is not to plague users with things like this. Obviously the JVM *has* the type information somewhere, otherwise it could not throw a conditional `ClassCastException`. Of course, the type information resides in the `Function` object and not in my class.

Comment: What seems obvious to you seems plain wrong to me. It's called type erasure for a reason. And it **can not** throw a ClassCastException. That's why you get the unchecked cast warning: the JVM cannot check that the cast is valid.

Comment: If you don't want to use the advice if @JBNizet, then you could bound your type variable so that you can use `instanceOf` to check for valid classes

Answer (score 1):

### How could a ClassCastException happen after Erasure?

After erasure is applied it can be hard to determine if an unchecked cast will trigger a `ClassCastException`. After all, the types are reduced to `Object`; why would casting to `Object` throw a casting exception? One cause for this error is generic code that calls non-generic implementations, where the types are explicitly stated. Take this example:

```
class Test<K> {
    public void foo(Object o) {
        bar((K) o);
    }

    public void bar(K k) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> test = new Test<>();
        test.foo("hello");
    }
}
```

The above example will still print `"hello"` correctly even though the generic type argument was an `Integer`. After erasure the method `bar` only requires an object:

```
public bar(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

If we extend `Test` and override `bar` where the type is explicit, then we will produce an error.

```
class TestInteger extends Test<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void bar(Integer k) {
        super.bar(k);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> test = new TestInteger();
        test.foo("hello");
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at TestInteger.bar(TestInteger.java:17)
    at Test.foo(TestInteger.java:9)
    at TestInteger.foo(TestInteger.java:17)
    at TestInteger.main(TestInteger.java:24)
```

In this child class, the method being overridden has a different signature than the method produced by `Test<K>`. The compiler creates a new overloaded method, called a *synthetic* or *bridge method*, in order to call `bar` as written in `TestInteger`. This bridge method is where the `ClassCastException` happens. It will look like bellow:

```
public void bar(Object k) {
    bar((Integer) k); //java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
}

public void bar(Integer k) {
    System.out.println(k); 
}
```

In your example, somewhere within the call to `keyExtractor.apply((E)o)` there lies a signature which relies on the explicit type causing the casting exception.

---

## Is it possible to check the type before casting?

Yes it is possible, but you will have to provide your `KeyedHashSet` class with extra data. You cannot directly get the `Class` object associated with a type parameter.

One way is to inject a `Class` type into your container and call [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)):

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator. The method returns `true` if the specified `Object` argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this `Class` object without raising a `ClassCastException`. It returns `false` otherwise.

```
public class Test<K> {
    final Class<K> clazz;
    Test(Class<K> clazz) { this.clazz = clazz; }

    public void foo(Object o) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(o)) {
            bar((K) o);
        }
    }
    ...

Test<Integer> test = new Test<>(Integer.class);
test.foo("string");
```

You could also use some validation strategy where the instance check is performed:

```
public class Test<K> {
    final Function<Object, Boolean> validator;
    Test(Function<Object, Boolean> validator) { this.validator = validator; }

    public void foo(Object o) {
        if (validator.apply(o)) {
            bar((K) o);
        }
    }
    ...

Test<Integer> test = new Test<>(k -> k instanceof Integer);
test.foo("string");
```

Another option could be to move the type checking inside the `Function<E,K> keyExtractor` instance and have the type parameters become `Function<Object,K> keyExtractor`, returning `null` if the type was incorrect.

*It would also be theoretically possible to reflectively examine method signatures for `keyExtractor` and get a `Class` instance, but it is not guaranteed that it's implementation will explicitly define the type parameters either.*

---

## Will checking instanceof slow down my application?

The execution time of `isInstance` is actually quite fast. [There's an interesting article](https://lsimons.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/instanceof-vs-classcastexception-performance-which-is-faster/) which experimentally compares the speeds of a try-catch with unsafe cast to an `isInstance` solution. In the results of the experiment,  the solution which explicitly checks for the type is only marginally slower than the unsafe solution.

Given that the performance penalty is so low I would opt to go the safe route and add class checking to your `contains` method. If you keep the try-catch solution as is, you may end up masking future bugs caused by the implementation of `keyExtractor.apply`, `map.get`, `elem.equals`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the details about the bridge methods required for the type binding to the lambda method. I wasn't aware of that. It turned out that Java uses the bytecode feature `invokedynamic` for this purpose. So there is really no static method signature that could be used as base for an automatic reflection at constructor time. :-( At least I could get rid of false positive capture of `ClassCastException` by checking `ex.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName() == getClass().getName()`.